# Javascript escapes the euro symbol as %u2AC instead of %u20AC

Tags: javascript, utf-8, escaping

my Javascript escapes the euro symbol as %u2AC instead of %u20AC. That is a problem because:

```
// My case:
var euroSymbol = '€';
var escapedEuroSymbil = escape(euroSymbol); // %u2AC
var backtoUnescaped = unescape(escapedEuroSymbil); // %u2AC
// Normal case:
var euroSymbol = '€';
var escapedEuroSymbil = escape(euroSymbol); // %u20AC
var backtoUnescaped = unescape(escapedEuroSymbil); // €
```

I know that using escape and unescape is not advaisable, but we store escaped data in db, so it can not be changed :(
Is there any way to make it escape that the normal way? Webpage has that tag:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-type" />
```

So I do not think it is a problem of coding.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there is absolutely no way that `escape('€')` can possibly return `'%u2AC'`.

Comment: right? I put that logic into jsfiddle and everything works perfectly. I could add that I work on cold fusion, but that might not make a difference

Comment: How do you expect two identical strings to return different results? I think you need to add a little more code from your actual implementation

Comment: Topic can be closed it is because ColdFusion has global culture settings setted as iso-8859-1 by default :)

Comment: Rather than closing the question you should create an answer so people that come upon the same case will easily see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

At some point turned out that it wasn't javascript but Coldfusion was configured to use urldecode(valueToBeChange, "iso-8859-1") on most values.